# mySQL - JOINS and ORDER BY one/zero/null value

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I struggle with that query.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts 
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta p1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = p1.post_id AND p1.meta_key = '_vip_post' ) 
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta p2 ON ( wp_posts.ID = p2.post_id AND p2.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' ) 
WHERE 1=1 
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'housing' 
    AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY
    COALESCE( p1.meta_key, 0 )+0 DESC,
    p1.meta_key DESC,
    if( p2.meta_key = '' or p2.meta_key is null, 1, 0) ASC, 
    wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

Yes, that's WordPress posts table. I'm joining postmeta table twice. `p1.meta_key` is `0`, `1` or `null` stored in a `longtext` field type. I need rows having `p1.meta_key`=`1` to be on top. Instead it puts on top the rows in which `p1.meta_key` is not `null` and orders them by last two `ORDER BY` directives.

**UPDATE**

Looks like I need to put my priorities right in this query. If I remove `wp_posts.post_date DESC` from the end of query or just ORDER BY like that:

```
p1.meta_key+0 = 1 DESC,
IF ( p2.meta_key = '' or p2.meta_key is null, 2, 1 )
```

rows are return just the way I want them but not chronologically.

This is what I get

```
+-----------------------+   +-------------+   +-----------------+
|       post_date       | + |  _vip_post  | + |  _thumbnail_id  |
+-----------------------+   +-------------+   +-----------------+
|  2012-03-18 21:47:33  |   |      0      |   |       533       |
|  2012-03-18 21:36:49  |   |      0      |   |       230       |
|  2012-03-18 20:19:50  |   |      0      |   |       170       |
|  2012-03-18 17:19:52  |   |      1      |   |        56       |
|  2012-03-20 10:42:00  |   |     null    |   |      null       |
|  2012-03-19 18:56:10  |   |     null    |   |      null       |
|  2012-03-16 03:12:32  |   |     null    |   |        ''       |
|  2012-03-15 16:40:22  |   |     null    |   |        ''       |
+-----------------------+   +-------------+   +-----------------+
```

**This is how i need it**

```
+-----------------------+   +-------------+   +-----------------+
|       post_date       | + |  _vip_post  | + |  _thumbnail_id  |
+-----------------------+   +-------------+   +-----------------+
|  2012-03-18 17:19:52  |   |      1      |   |        56       |
|  2012-03-18 21:47:33  |   |      0      |   |       533       |
|  2012-03-18 21:36:49  |   |      0      |   |       230       |
|  2012-03-18 20:19:50  |   |      0      |   |       170       |
|  2012-03-20 10:42:00  |   |     null    |   |      null       |
|  2012-03-19 18:56:10  |   |     null    |   |      null       |
|  2012-03-16 03:12:32  |   |     null    |   |        ''       |
|  2012-03-15 16:40:22  |   |     null    |   |        ''       |
+-----------------------+   +-------------+   +-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

try...

```
order by
   case when p1.meta_key is null then 3
        when p1.meta_key = 1 then 1
        when p1.meta_key is 0 then 2 end,
   case p2.meta_key is null then 2
        else 1 end,
   wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

The order by here checks first on the p1.meta_key. Check NULL first and set to 3.  If not, if its 1, the uses 1 as its first-level sort order.  If = 0, then 2 as its sort order.

Now, within the above sort, you want the dates sorted in descending order, but put any NULL dates at the END of the list, so we need to qualify if there's a null value or not...  So second case works similar to the first.  If the date is null, then put it SECOND, if it has a date, it gets FIRST.

Finally, the actual date level.  Sort by the post date descending for the most recent dates first (which ALL actual dates will appear before any nulls) per respective p1.meta_key grouping.

Comment: Still no luck. While trying desperately variations I removed the last `ORDER BY` condition `wp_posts.post_date DESC` and it sorted by `p1.meta_key` just right but not chronologically.

Comment: @Zlatev, can you post what your results ARE looking like in your answer, and show an additional column of the actual order you want them sorted... We'll get you there...

Comment: Same results as before. It seems to me that `post_date` weighs down over `p1.meta_key` for some reason.

Comment: @Zlatev, did you completely remove your order by clause and apply this one?  I would try one at a time... just do the order by with p1.meta_key CASE/END construct and see what that gets... THEN add p2.meta_key CASE/END and see if that properly sub-sorts within the first, THEN add the post date.  If you need to, you might do a COALESCE( wp_posts.post_date, '1900-01-01' ) DESC for the last order by to prevent NULLs as the post date "order" qualifier.